# WebLogic 10.3.6 java.text.SimpleDateFormat variables does not work in log file name

Tags: java, date, format, weblogic

I'm trying to set up my own log file name format and testing this:

> To include a time and date stamp in the file name when the log file is
>   rotated, add java.text.SimpleDateFormat variables to the file name.
>   Surround each variable with percentage (%) characters.
>
> For example, if the file name is defined to be
>   myserver_%yyyy%_%MM%_%dd%_%hh%_%mm%.log, the log file will be named
>   myserver_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm.log.
>
> When the log file is rotated, the rotated file name contains the date
>   stamp. For example, if the log file is rotated for the first time on 2
>   April, 2003 at 10:05 AM, the log file that contains the old messages
>   will be named myserver_2003_04_02_10_05.log00001.

But result is:

> -rw-rw-r--  1 weblogic weblogic  20K Jan 21 13:00 myserver_yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm.log

Any ideas, what can be wrong?

Comment: This looks correct: " the log file will be named myserver_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm.log.".

It should appear with correct data after log is rotated.

Comment: I use "Rotate log file on startup" option. After weblogic restart filename is "myserver_yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm.log"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, this is not rotated log file. This is current log, and it will be named correctly after real rotation.

Thanks to devwebcl